# input type file multiple argument type mismatch

Tags: java, javascript, html5, struts

Estoy intentando implementar una funcionalidad en la que se puedan subir al servidor tantos ficheros como se desee seleccionar. Lo estoy haciendo con:

```
<form id="uploadForm" action="uploadFilesDPT.do" styleId="withoutPadding" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" styleClass="withoutPadding">
<input **type="file"** name="theFile" id="attachFiles" onchange="updateSize();" **multiple**/>selected files: <span id="fileNum">0</span>; total size: <span id="fileSize">0</span>
```

El problema lo tengo en el Bean, si creo un atributo `FormFile[]` o `List<FormFile>`, `MultipartFile files` o `MultipartFile[] files`:

```
public class UploadForm extends ActionForm {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private FormFile[] theFile;
private MultipartFile[] files;



public FormFile[] getTheFile() {
    return theFile;
}
public void setTheFile(FormFile[] theFile) {

    this.theFile = theFile;
}    

public void setFiles(MultipartFile[] file) {
    this.files = file;
}

public MultipartFile[] getFiles() {
    return files;
}
```

}

Siempre obtengo el mismo error, ¿Cómo lo soluciono?:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: BeanUtils.populate",argument type
>   mismatch.

Comment: Buen día y bienvenido. Por favor, siempre que tengas dudas relacionadas con código, coloca el mismo para que los usuarios lo puedan observar y analizar; de esta manera te darán una respuesta concreta.

Comment: Mitsu, Así mejor!!

Comment: y la clase Action???